# Bluetooth suddenly turn off and won't turn on on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, connection, ubuntu-drivers

I'm using Ubuntu since a week now, the only issue I have is the Bluetooth suddenly stop working and turning on is disabled in settings saying "No Bluetooth found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth".

In the terminal I tried the following:

```
$ sudo -i
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Then: `bluetoothctl`

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power off
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

Is like someone disconnect the bluetooth module. Restarting can resolve the issue.
I use a bluetooth mouse (Logitech MX Ergo) and a bluetooth headphones.
If I restart the bluetooth start working again.

I use `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` and `Linux 5.8.0-40-generic` kernel.

Comment: There are some bugs in the 5.8 kernel. I found a couple already. I suggest to revert tho the LTS 5.4.

Comment: You mean select Linux kernel 5.4 at the start?

Comment: Select it, and if it works well, then remove the 5.8 kernel.